# Difference between binary file and BLOB

Tags: blob, binaryfiles, binary-data

Watching [this video about how to design Tinder](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tndzLznxq40&t=29s), at 06:50 a point is being made about files vs BLOBS.

I wonder what the difference is between a large binary file and a BLOB (binary large object).

Do they differ by

- The method of access
- The method of backup
- Sharding?

What is the origin of difference? They sound quite similar to me.

Comment: a "blob" is just "a bunch of bytes", it isn't necessary a "file".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the video refers to BLOB (binary large object), it doesn't refer to any old collection of binary information (file). According to this [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_large_object), it specifically means

> collection of binary data stored as a single entity in a database
>   management system.

The distinction lies in the "database management system". A BLOB is managed by the DBMS, although it might still be stored in a file system. However, other files are stored directly stored in the file system, and often only a URI is stored in the database.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the difference from this answer

Comment: Sorry :) A BLOB lives is managed by a database (the database system might decide to still store the file in a file system though, but that is abstracted away from you). A file lives on a file system, and in this case, you'd only have the URI of the file in the database.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are asking about what the difference between normal files and BLOBs is. Normal files contain information about the media itself(image,video,file) and also metadata(name,size,..). BLOBS contain only the binary data about the file which means they dont have the metadata. Just pure binary data about the image, video or whatever.

But if you take a look at a BLOB it is not ones and zeros. That is because it is in hexadecimal or base64 format and not in binary format. But when your machine is ready to use that blob it converts the hexadecimal to binary.

If you want to store an image in a database, then you create a BLOB from the image first and then store that BLOB in the database. The metadata about the image(name, size,...) will be stored too in another row. And then when you want to get back that image, you extract both the BLOB which is the actual image and also the metadata and then combine the two to form a usable image which is a file.

---

Binary file contains binary while BLOB contains binary data too but not directly stored in zeros and ones like binary file but in hexadecimal format, which will need to be converted to binary when the file is ready to be used by the computer.